# Implementation of the Grad-CAM algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have the next Python code:

tubby_output = model.output[:, 281]

last_conv_layer = model.get_layer('block5_conv3')

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

    grads = tape.gradient(tubby_output, last_conv_layer.output)
    pooled_grads = K.mean(grads, axis=(0,1,2))
    iterate = K.function([model.input],
                         [pooled_grads, last_conv_layer.output[0]])
    pooled_grads_value, conv_layer_output_value = iterate([img_tensor]) 
for i in range(512):
    conv_layer_output_value[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]
heatmap = np.mean(conv_layer_output_value, axis=-1)`
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    <ipython-input-128-5b66da230a26> in <module>
     13     # Вектор с формой (512,), каждый элемент которого определяет
     14     # интенсивность градиента для заданного канала в карте признаков
---> 15     pooled_grads = K.mean(grads, axis=(0,1,2))
     17     iterate = K.function([model.input],
c:\users\79278\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in mean(x, axis, keepdims)
   2112       A tensor with the mean of elements of `x`.
   2113   """
-> 2114   if x.dtype.base_dtype == d types_module.bool:
   2115     x = math_ops.cast(x, floatx())
   2116   return math_ops.reduce_mean(x, axis, keepdims)
AttributeError: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Help me solve this problem! Thanks

Comment: You are not using gradient tape correctly, I suggest that you look at the documentation, you need to put calculations that will lead to a gradient inside the "with" statement